# pulling from a repo is causing merge conflicts with 8 year old files, despite regularly pulling from this repo

Tags: git, git-merge, pull, merge-conflict-resolution

**Context**

I am developing `alpha`.

`alpha` is a clone of `beta` (not a fork).

`beta` is an ever evolving project that I am tracking.

**Problem**

Once a month, I run `git pull beta master` to get the latest changes and updates. I last successfully did this 26 days ago.

Yesterday when I ran `git pull beta master`, I started to get merge conflicts that originate from a commit in 2015.

**Goals**

- Pull all the updates to `beta master` in the last 26 days
- Pull from `beta master` in the future without issue.

**Questions**

I do not know how else to debug or troubleshoot this, and I'm hoping somebody can answer:

1. Did I do something to `alpha` that would cause this to happen? If so, how can I fix it?
2. Are there things on `beta` I can check to see if this on their end?

**Troubleshooting**

1. I cannot just deny the incoming conflicts - my project is completely inoperable due to the changes that are made by the files that successfully merged *without* conflicts.
2. I have tried reverting my repo back 100~ commits and THEN pulling from `beta`, and the same problem occurs.
3. I am a contributor to `beta`, and me (nor the other contributors) can see anything that changed on `beta` that would cause this.
4. This also happens when I `cherry-pick` any commit from `beta`.

Comment: Check the basics.... so, you had done a merge some 20+ days ago. What was the top commit from`beta/master` that was merged back then? Then, a basic check. What is the output of `git merge-base that-commit-id beta/master`. If there was _no_ history rewrite, that should give you the same commit id that had been merged a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't explicitly telling it to rebase but when I ran `git pull --rebase=false`, I got was I was expecting. No idea how that happened, but glad its resolved now.

I would love if somebody was able to explain how this happened in the first place, so that people googling in the future that find this, can avoid the pitfalls.